# Unusual segue difficulty

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

So I have a scroll view that is loaded up with photos and then will transition to a detail view when a photo is tapped. Everything works fine as long as I do not leave the scroll view or detail view. When I exit though from the scrollview back to the main menu and try the scrollview again, I get no response whatsover from a tap on a photo. When you exit out again and try again, I get the error below even though the segue is exactly the same as the first and second time. Any theories on what has gone wrong?

```
Warning: Attempt to present <detailscreen: 0x1f01a410> on <Scrollstream: 0x1f0b6d80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: It's saying your `Scrollstream` isn't part of a view hierarchy which is being presented to the user. I'm guessing you've got a variable for your `Scrollstream` out of your main menu, but it's not using the one in the variable, it's creating a new instance. Just a guess with no code or anything though.

Comment: Interesting. So you are saying that I have a variable or the original scroll view interfering with the new one (since my design doesn't dismiss the viewcontroller)?

Comment: That's my guess. It's clearly saying you can't present detailscreen by  attaching it to something the user can't see. If it works the first time and not the second it's usually because you think you are re-using something, but it created a new one instead (usually based on a coding mistake).